# Find multiple matches starting with specific symbols and then consecutive occurrences of specific words and patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have the following kind of string `"sometext1 §§ 12 Abs. 5, 13a, 14 Satz 1 Nr. 3, 9, 8 sometext2"`. I want to find a `§§` substring and all consecutive occurrences of `Abs.`, `und`, `Satz` and `Nr.` as well as digits with a single character like `13a`.

Examples:

```
"Die Anzahl der §§ 12 Abs. 5, 13a, 14 Satz 1 und 8 kann variieren. Für die §§ 15a, 18 Abs. 5, 21 und 23 Satz 3 trifft dies nicht zu.
```

Here I want to get `12 Abs. 5, 13a, 14 Satz 1 und 8` and `15a, 18 Abs. 5, 21 und 23 Satz 3`.

I used the following regex `'r'§§ (.*)? ^(?!Satz|Abs.|Nr.|\d+[a-z]| |,)'`.

Comment: `sometext2` can vary and is not always `sometext2`. It might be `dfsdf`

Comment: You are right. it finds too many matches

Comment: While you are still thinking about the requirements, try `§§\s*((?:Satz|Abs\.|Nr\.|\d+[a-z]?|und|[\s,])+)(?<=\w)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DxveT/1). Note I included `und` here and made the letter after number optional. If this logic of "whitelisting" words in the match is working, this can be a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to solve my problem and meet all the requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
§§\s*((?:Satz|Abs\.|Nr\.|\d+[a-z]?|und|[\s,])+)(?<=\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DxveT/1). *Details*:

- `§§` - a literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:Satz|Abs\.|Nr\.|\d+[a-z]?|und|[\s,])+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more occurrences of `Satz`, `Abs.`, `Nr.`, one or more digits optionally followed by a lowercase ASCII letter, `und`, whitespace or comma.
- `(?<=\w)` - the char immediately on the left must be a word char.